# Как написать cron expression для Hangfire для выполнения задач каждые N секунд

Tags: c#, .net, cron, hangfire, ncron

Мне в .NET проекте нужно выполнять задачи раз в N секунд, на данный момент мне удалось добиться примерно раз в 15 секунд. Как сделать например раз в 16 секунд или раз в 5 секунд я на данный момент не понял.

Мой код для создания повторяющейся задачи в HangFire с использованием Cron выглядит так:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(guid, () => Console.WriteLine("Test"), "*/1 * * * * *");
```

Может быть кто-то имеет опыт создания повторяющихся задач с любой переиодичностью в секундах?
Может быть есть другой способ в HangFire создать повторяющуюся задачу каждые N секунд, без Cron Expression?

Comment: Здесь есть ответ с пример запуска каждые 20 секунд.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367398/hangfire-recurring-tasks-under-minute

Comment: Похоже, что там может быть решение. Чуть позже проанализирую. Спасибо!